# Can insert on tables with FK impact operations on other tables that have FKs to the same table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

Let's assume that we have the following tables on an **InnoDB** database:

- user (id_user, name)
- log (id_log, id_user, info)
- message (id_message, id_user_from, id_user_to, message)

The `id_user` column on `log` and `id_user_from` and `id_user_to` on `message` tables are FK to `user(id_user)`.

As I understand it, when we make an insert on `log` table mysql [will create a shared lock on the related record](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html) on `user`, if exists. [If another transaction try to get a shared lock, it will works fine. If  another transaction try to get a exclusive lock, it will have to wait until the first transaction finishes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html).

My question is: If another transaction try to make an insert or update on `message` referencing the same record on `user` it will be impacted by the insert on `log`? I don't think so, because this transaction will get a shared lock on the record too, but I read on some old articles (from 10 years ago) that this can be an issue. If it is a case, isolation level has some impact on this? Again, I don't think so.

Comment: Use indexes; it makes life simpler.

Comment: The engine automatically creates indexes if we don't, so let's consider that the indexes exists.

Comment: What engine creates what indexes??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear. This happens when you create a FK on InnoDB and not create the index by yourself. Docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

My attitudes in this area:

- Make transactions so fast that there are rarely any conflicts.
- Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to "lock" rows that I am about to update.  (Unless there is a way to avoid them.)
- FKs imply extra checks.  These take time.  And the checks are *usually* redundant.
- I don't use FK `CASCADE` since I like to see all the interactions in the same code -- namely the code between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.
- I don't use non-cascading FKs; I debug my code instead.
- I do use `INDEXes` and I want to know exactly what indexes exist and not be surprised by extra (redundant?) ones created by FKs.
- Do check for errors after every SQL statement.  These can be surprise deadlocks.
- Check for errors even after `COMMIT`.  This is in case the app is ever migrated to Galera or InnoDB Cluster.
- Restart at the `BEGIN` if there is a deadlock.
- Beware of "burned" `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids.  (That's a lengthy discussion of its own.)

Back to your question.

There are cases where InnoDB takes a stronger (eg, X vs S) lock than it needs to.  This *may* be because of an edge case that is too costly to check for.  Your example may (or may not) be an example of such -- I don't have enough brain cells think it through at the moment.  I go back to my first bullet item -- make the transaction fast enough so the problem goes away.